# SPFX Webpart Properties pane not visible in MS Teams personal tab

Tags: microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I have added the SPFX webpart in MS Team as personal app but i didn't found any option to open the webpart property pane

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tZCe.png)

Comment: Microsoft Teams tabs using SharePoint Framework. Using SharePoint Framework significantly simplifies Teams tab development process as Teams tabs can be automatically hosted within SharePoint without any need for external services. Please check [Build Microsoft Teams tab using SharePoint Framework - Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab) and [SPFx web part samples for tabs, channels, and group sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-channel-group/spfx)

Comment: I already added SPFX webpart in the Team personal Tab but I am didn't found any option  to set the value in Webpart Property Pane

Comment: could you please check [Add method to handle the selection of an item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls#add-method-to-handle-the-selection-of-an-item)? try if that helps

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding Copying answer from comments:
Microsoft Teams tabs using SharePoint Framework. Using SharePoint Framework significantly simplifies Teams tab development process as Teams tabs can be automatically hosted within SharePoint without any need for external services. Please check [Build Microsoft Teams tab using SharePoint Framework - Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab) and [SPFx web part samples for tabs, channels, and group sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-channel-group/spfx). To set value of web part please check  [Add method to handle the selection of an item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls#add-method-to-handle-the-selection-of-an-item)